# What's is meant by the dir() built-in function returns "(some of) the attributes of the given object"?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wonder whether the documentation is wrong for the `dir()` built-in function. In particular, what object attributes may not be part of the list returned by `dir()`?

For both class objects and other objects, the documentation says that the list contains "its attributes", which means a full set (and not "some of") of attributes?

Python v. 3.9 @ macOS 10.15.7

```
Help on built-in function dir in module builtins:

dir(...)
    dir([object]) -> list of strings

    If called without an argument, return the names in the current scope.
    Else, return an alphabetized list of names comprising (some of) the attributes
    of the given object, and of attributes reachable from it.
    If the object supplies a method named __dir__, it will be used; otherwise
    the default dir() logic is used and returns:
      for a module object: the module's attributes.
      for a class object:  its attributes, and recursively the attributes
        of its bases.
      for any other object: its attributes, its class's attributes, and
        recursively the attributes of its class's base classes.
```

Comment: I have a good read about this at: [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir) `dir function`.

Comment: `dir`'s behavior can be defined by the type, the `__dir__` hook. You should heed the note in the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir0: "Because dir() is supplied primarily as a convenience for use at an interactive prompt, it tries to supply an interesting set of names more than it tries to supply a rigorously or consistently defined set of names, and its detailed behavior may change across releases. For example, metaclass attributes are not in the result list when the argument is a class." `dir` is a convenience function, not rigorously specified

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Python, an attribute is not necessarily a thing on an object, or a field on the class. For example, [`__getattr__` can define arbitrary attributes on-demand](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-attribute-access). As such, there is no general, robust way to discover an attribute without actually accessing it.

> If the object does not provide `__dir__()`, the function tries its best to gather information from the object’s `__dict__` attribute, if defined, and from its type object. The resulting list is not necessarily complete, and may be inaccurate when the object has a custom `__getattr__()`.

There is no fixed set of attributes which are *not* covered by `dir` – `dir` uses a heuristic and the `__dir__` hook, so *any* attribute may-or-may-not be discovered. In general, for a well-behaved object one can expect public attributes to be visible to `dir`. Private and especially special attributes are candidates to be excluded from `dir`.

```py
>>> '__dict__' in dir(object)
False
>>> hasattr(object, '__dict__')
True
```

> Note: Because `dir()` is supplied primarily as a convenience for use at an interactive prompt, *it tries to supply an interesting set of names more than it tries to supply a rigorously or consistently defined set* of names, and its detailed behavior may change across releases. *For example, metaclass attributes are not in the result list when the argument is a class.*

(All quotes from [Documentation » The Python Standard Library » Built-in Functions: dir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir))

Comment: Thank you, @MisterMiyagi. *There is no fixed set of attributes which are not covered by `dir`* - what do you mean by "fixed set of attributes"?

Comment: Objects always provide `__dir__()`? If you define a new class, objects automatically have a `__dir__()` method.

Comment: For me, both private attributes (`self._foo`) and mangled attributes (`self.__foo`) are shown in the output of `dir()`.

Comment: What's the default implementation for `__getattr__()`? Is it simply `object.getattr()`?

Comment: @Shuzheng The "fixed set of attribute" means there is no list of names that will never or always occur in ``__dir__``. For example, as the answer shows ``__dict__`` is not in ``dir(object)``, but you cannot rely on ``__dict__`` *never* being in any result of ``dir`` for an arbitrary object.

Comment: Alright. **There is no fixed set of attributes which are not covered by `dir`** sounds like: "`dir()` covers all fixed set of attributes`.

Comment: See it like this: ``dir`` *may* cover *any* set of attributes.